# Osascript custom function not interpreting command string properly

Tags: bash, macos, osascript

I have this function that I've written:

```
function alert { 
    command='display alert '
    content="${1} message ${2}"
    concat=$command$content
    osascript -e "${concat}"
}
```

When executed like:

```
alert 'Title' 'Message'
```

I get the error message:

```
25:27: syntax error: A end of script can’t go after this “my”. (-2740)
```

Why is that the case?

For reference this command works perfectly:

```
osascript -e 'display alert "Title" message "Message"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not putting quotes around the message and title in `content`. So they're being treated as variable names by the OSAScript interpreter.

```
function alert { 
    command='display alert '
    content="\"${1}\" message \"${2}\""
    concat=$command$content
    osascript -e "${concat}"
}
```